# Magento Data Migrate tool error "Attribute vat_id does not exist in the type customer_address"

Tags: customer-address, magento2-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate Magento 1.8.1.0 to 2.1.6. when i run data migration, i get the following error:

> - [2017-04-22 20:28:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:56][ERROR]: Attribute vat_id does not exist in the type customer_address
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:58][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:58][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:58][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:58][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:58][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:58][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
> - [2017-04-22 20:28:58][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started

i already found this [post](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/230) and found that i already have vat_id in eav_attribute table!!

Answer (score 0):

The attribute should exist in both `eav_attribute` and `eav_entity_type` with relevant attribute types. I guess you do not have a record in `eav_entity_type` table. You can check it by running following query.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    eav_entity_type et
        JOIN
    eav_attribute ea ON et.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
WHERE
    et.entity_type_code = 'customer_address' and  ea.attribute_code='vat_id';
```

-- Update ---

If the above does not return any result run following to add missing record.

```
INSERT INTO `eav_entity_type`
(`entity_type_id`,
`entity_type_code`,
`entity_model`,
`attribute_model`,
`entity_table`,
`value_table_prefix`,
`entity_id_field`,
`is_data_sharing`,
`data_sharing_key`,
`default_attribute_set_id`,
`increment_model`,
`increment_per_store`,
`increment_pad_length`,
`increment_pad_char`,
`additional_attribute_table`,
`entity_attribute_collection`)
VALUES
('2', 'customer_address', 'customer/address', 'customer/attribute', 'customer/address_entity', NULL, NULL, '1', 'default', '2', NULL, '0', '8', '0', 'customer/eav_attribute', 'customer/address_attribute_collection');
```

Comment: I'm a newbie when it come SQL, your patience would be greatly appreciated. i run your statement from phpmyadmin but i got `#1046 - No database selected` so i tried and put the DB name at the left side of the statement to be: 

`SELECT 
    *
FROM
    DBName.eav_entity_type et
        JOIN
    eav_attribute ea ON et.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
WHERE
    et.entity_type_code = 'customer_address' and  ea.attribute_code='vat_id'` and ended up with zero rows

Comment: i checked using phpmyadmin and i found that the table already have a row with the same info, with the same primary key (2)